# I want use wechat js-sdk chooseVideo, uploadVideo api.the result is "chooseVideo:fail_nopermission to execute"

Tags: javascript, java, wechat

When i use `wechat js-sdk`, i want use `chooseVideo`, `uploadVideo`  api. the result is `"chooseVideo:fail_nopermission to execute"`.
I am sure, `wx.config(wxConfigData)` is right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOTzT.png)

Answer (score 0):

`wx.chooseVideo` is an API of WeChat "mini program" ([doc](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/debug/wxadoc/dev/api/media-video.html)). It's NOT an API of WeChat JS-SDK: in JS-SDK's [document](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki), no `chooseVideo` would be found.